# Images are not getting displayed on index.html , I'm editing a hotel template in Django, just the basics

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-staticfiles

my views.py looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

## Application definition

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

## Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

my index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Deluxe - Free Bootstrap 4 Template by Colorlib</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    

    <section class="home-slider owl-carousel">
      <div class="slider-item" style="background-image:url({% static 'images/bg_1.jpg' %});">

        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row no-gutters slider-text align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-12 ftco-animate text-center">
            <div class="text mb-5 pb-3">

                <h1 class="mb-3">Welcome To Deluxe</h1>
                <h2>Hotels &amp; Resorts</h2>
                <img src="{% static 'images/bg_1.jpg' %}" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want the images to get displayed after running the server, want to get rid of this doubt